# How to use a manifest embedded as a resource? (Windows XP/Vista-style controls)

Tags: winapi, configuration, resources, manifest

I have a manifest embedded as a Windows resource.  But what's the right way to apply it?

More specifically:

I have my .manifest file.  It's the standard one to make an app use controls in the Windows XP/Vista visual style.  When applied by being in the same directory as the .exe and suitably named, it works.

However, this approach is rather cumbersome.  I'd like my .exe to be self-contained.  Clearly it can be done, given that many of the apps on my computer manage to use the modern style without a separate manifest file.

So I had a look around, and finally found embedding the manifest as a resource.  So I've added this line to my .rc file:

```
1 RT_MANIFEST "mdiedit.exe.manifest"
```

But what do I do next?

**Edit:** If it helps you to know, my program is written in D and built using the Digital Mars D and resource compilers.  No IDE.  But I'd expect any solution that works in C(++), when built using command-line tools, to work in D as well.

Comment: Well, can you verify that the EXE actually contains the manifest? I don't know if your environment can, but Visual Studio can open EXE files using the resource editor. If you can open the RT_MANIFEST resource and verify the contents.

Comment: Which is to say, on the surface of it you are doing everything correctly. If the manifest is in the EXE there is no separate API that needs to be called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RT_MANIFEST` is a define, so make sure your resource file includes the correct header, or just replace `RT_MANIFEST` with 24

Comment: That worked, thanks!  (Lesson learned: the Windows headers shipped with DMC are out of date.)  How actually does the resource compiler interpret an unknown resource type?  Are they just like resource IDs in that they can be words or numbers?

Comment: Resource ID's can be strings or numbers. ...And if it worked, how about marking the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the .rc file to your project yet?  Alternatively, use your development environment's resource compiler, such as brcc32.exe or rc.exe, to compile the .rc file into a .res file, and then add that file to your project.

Comment: Already done.  No effect.  (If I hadn't, then none of my dialogs, menus or icons would be working.)  Maybe your IDE automagically adds runtime code when you do this?

Comment: Nope, there is no runtime code involved.  It compiles .rc files directly into the executable resources.