# Compiler/Linker is not working with .manifest files

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, manifest, msys2

***Some background:***

I work with the c++ language in the Code::Blocks IDE on Windows 10. Usually, when I install Code::Blocks I use the mingw-setup build so I can just get right into programming. Due to this I have no experience with setting up compilers and whatnot. Recently a friend asked me to make a program for him so i took him up on it and decided to start working. When it came the time to build it didnt work and I learned that the compiler was outdated so I moved to a new one.

***The Problem:***

When I tried to  make the program for my friend require administrator perms with the new compiler, I made my normal manifest file. The program built and all was good but I realized that my program was not requiring administrator permissions. I went to my old compiler to see if I had messed something up and I had not, the new compiler just *didn't* work with the manifest file.

***What I Previously Had Been Able To Do:***

Previously, before I changed my compiler, I was able to put the *name*.exe.manifest file into the same folder as the *name*.exe file, build it, then I was golden. Now, even when putting it into the folder it doesnt work.

***Questions:***

- Are there any MSYS2 packages I can use to fix this?
- What exactly is the problem?
- How can I prevent this in the future?
- Besides MSYS2 packages, how else can I fix this?
- Some files from my custom build are missing in comparison to the Code::Blocks one, If I copy them over to my build, will it work?

***What I Tried:***

- I have tried putting the manifest file in several different folders
- I have tried changing the linker settings to include "-o *Dir/SubDir/Manifest*"
- I have tried having the linker search different directories
- I have tried researching the problem and asking around different places. (My conclusion was that it was a problem with a compiler/linker or I didnt have a file I needed.

***My Maifest File Code:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="NAME HERE"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>DESCRIPTION HERE</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

***Mingw Compiler (Code::Blocks):***

[Image: (In MingW: The Normal Code::Blocks Build)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REZw1.png)

[Image: (In MingW: The Normal Code::Blocks Build) > Bin Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn6ZN.png)

***MSYS2 Compiler (Custom Compiler):***

[Image: MSYS2 Mingw64: Custom Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WTmx.png)

[Image: MSYS2 Mingw64: Custom Build > Bin folder*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuOAs.png)

*If you look, the normal Code::Blocks Mingw compiler's bin directory pales in comparison to my build's.

==========================================================================

I will be happy to answer any questions you have!

Comment: Is this a 64 bit build?  If so, you might need `processorArchitecture="*"` in your manifest file.

Comment: @PaulSanders It is, but my manifest file worked with the old compiler and was a 64 bit compiler. Though i can try adding it on, where would you recommend me putting it?

Comment: In place of `processorArchitecture="X86"`.  Worth a try, anyway.

Comment: no that didnt seem to solve the problem, I do have a large number of libraries, could that be the problem?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so.  You might try embedding your manifest as a resource (that's what I do), see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402137/how-to-use-a-manifest-embedded-as-a-resource-windows-xp-vista-style-controls

Comment: I dont completely understand, should i add "#RT_MANIFEST "name.exe.manifest"" to my .cpp file?

Comment: I have `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "MyApp.exe.manifest"`

Comment: Just to make sure its in the cpp file itself, right? or some other file?

Comment: It's in the .rc file.

Comment: Ive never made an .rc file, do I have to compile this too?

Comment: Yes you do, and link the resulting `.res` file into your .exe, but I don't know how to do that in MSYS2, sorry.  With the Microsoft tools, the resource compiler is called `rc.exe`.

Comment: ahh, ok, where do i download microsoft tools?

Comment: There's something out there called Visual Studio Community Edition.  That's the only free download I know of.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! ill see what i can do because visual studio is VERY big

Comment: You don't need Visual Studio for this. Use `windres` that should already be installed in your MSYS2.

Comment: @PaulSanders I just downloaded VS today, could you explain how i make a .rc file, how to build using visual studio (+ how to build without running code), and how to link the ,res file (is it just #include <*name*.res>)?

Comment: Track down rc.exe on your system and use it to compile your .rc file to a .res file.  Then include the .res file in the list of files you link together to produce your final .exe.

Comment: @PaulSanders Im sorry but where do i link the file? the VS UI is confusing and i can seem to find it in the docs

Comment: In the property pages for the project, add the .res file to Linker -> Input.

Comment: @PaulSanders im sorry for the very late reply, but when I go to add a resource im left with a bunch of options such as accelerator, bitmap, cursor, dialog, etc... what do i click?

Comment: @PaulSanders Or if you could, just walk me through all the steps you would do to create a program that prompts the admin response

Comment: SO is not really the place to teach you how to use a complex and feature-rich IDE like Visual Studio.  You might like to take a look at this: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/getting-started/